# Storing a variable into a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In an attempt to better learn Rails and I'm building a simple Blackjack game, but I'm running into a problem of storing the variable. I understand how to store user-genereated data into the db using form_for, but I'm struggling to create a random number and put it in the db.

> > @hand = rand(9) + 2

I have "hand" as a field in my db, just curious how to store this random number. Any help anyone could provide to point me in the right direction would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some example code:

```
@game = Game.find(42)
@game.hand = rand(9) + 2
@game.save
```

In this case, I'm assuming that `Game` is a model in your Rails application. Fields (or "database columns", if you prefer) in the `games` table you can access and set by using their names - so we're saving our `rand` value into a field named `hand`.

(Of course, you have to create that field first - either by having created it via some scaffolding, or by creating a database migration to add that column).

Likewise, to read back the `hand` variable.

```
@game = Game.find(42)
@game.hand
```

Comment: This is great. Just one question, what does find(24) represent?

Comment: `find(42)` = return the record whose id is 42 :). (nothing to do with your problem exactly, but I put it there for context - you will have retrieved the record somehow anyway.

Comment: That's what I thought. Just checking. Thanks, @RyanWilcox!